# Update ListProperties in the Google Docs API

Tags: google-docs-api

My office about to start producing a large number of Google Docs with bulleted lists in a particular structure.

```
PART 1 - TEXT HERE
1.1 - TEXT HERE
    A. TEXT HERE
        1. TEXT HERE
            a. TEXT HERE
                1) TEXT HERE
                    (a) TEXT HERE
```

Unfortunately, this does not match any of the default list options.

[image]

Nor does it seem like you can select the numbering format at each level. So I'm looking into using the Google Docs API to both apply this custom list format, and validate/update the lists of existing documents.

Microsoft Word has the ability to define a new list style where the numbering can be set at each level.

[image]

Opening a MS Word doc in Google Docs with this formatting, and choosing File->Save As Google Doc creates a Google Doc with the desired list structure.

[image]

So Google Docs is capable of representing a list with the structure we desire, but I'd prefer to not propose a workflow that depends on Microsoft Word.

When I retrieve this test document from the Google Docs API I can see this custom list structure under `lists.{listID}.listProperties.nestingLevels`:

```
[
    {
        "bulletAlignment": "START",
        "glyphType": "DECIMAL",
        "glyphFormat": "PART %0 - ",
        "indentFirstLine": {
            "unit": "PT"
        },
        "indentStart": {
            "magnitude": 18,
            "unit": "PT"
        },
        "textStyle": {},
        "startNumber": 1
    },
    {
        "bulletAlignment": "START",
        "glyphType": "DECIMAL",
        "glyphFormat": "%0.%1 - ",
        "indentFirstLine": {
            "magnitude": 18,
            "unit": "PT"
        },
        "indentStart": {
            "magnitude": 36,
            "unit": "PT"
        },
        "textStyle": {},
        "startNumber": 1
    },
    {
        "bulletAlignment": "START",
        "glyphType": "UPPER_ALPHA",
        "glyphFormat": "%2.",
        "indentFirstLine": {
            "magnitude": 36,
            "unit": "PT"
        },
        "indentStart": {
            "magnitude": 54,
            "unit": "PT"
        },
        "textStyle": {},
        "startNumber": 1
    },
    {
        "bulletAlignment": "START",
        "glyphSymbol": "●",
        "glyphFormat": "%3",
        "indentFirstLine": {
            "magnitude": 54,
            "unit": "PT"
        },
        "indentStart": {
            "magnitude": 72,
            "unit": "PT"
        },
        "textStyle": {},
        "startNumber": 1
    },
    {
        "bulletAlignment": "START",
        "glyphType": "ALPHA",
        "glyphFormat": "%4.",
        "indentFirstLine": {
            "magnitude": 72,
            "unit": "PT"
        },
        "indentStart": {
            "magnitude": 90,
            "unit": "PT"
        },
        "textStyle": {},
        "startNumber": 1
    },
    {
        "bulletAlignment": "START",
        "glyphType": "DECIMAL",
        "glyphFormat": "%5)",
        "indentFirstLine": {
            "magnitude": 90,
            "unit": "PT"
        },
        "indentStart": {
            "magnitude": 108,
            "unit": "PT"
        },
        "textStyle": {},
        "startNumber": 1
    },
    {
        "bulletAlignment": "START",
        "glyphType": "ALPHA",
        "glyphFormat": "(%6)",
        "indentFirstLine": {
            "magnitude": 108,
            "unit": "PT"
        },
        "indentStart": {
            "magnitude": 126,
            "unit": "PT"
        },
        "textStyle": {},
        "startNumber": 1
    },
    {
        "bulletAlignment": "START",
        "glyphType": "DECIMAL",
        "glyphFormat": "- ",
        "indentFirstLine": {
            "magnitude": 126,
            "unit": "PT"
        },
        "indentStart": {
            "magnitude": 144,
            "unit": "PT"
        },
        "textStyle": {},
        "startNumber": 1
    },
    {
        "bulletAlignment": "START",
        "glyphType": "DECIMAL",
        "glyphFormat": "%8- ",
        "indentFirstLine": {
            "magnitude": 144,
            "unit": "PT"
        },
        "indentStart": {
            "magnitude": 162,
            "unit": "PT"
        },
        "textStyle": {},
        "startNumber": 1
    }
]
```

However, unless I'm missing something I do not see any way to update these `nestingLevel`s through the Google Docs API [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate).

<strike>The `document.lists` can only set when [create](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create)ing a new document from scratch.</strike>

**UPDATE**

Ignore my previous statement above about the `document.create` method. The documentation is very misleading. The "Request Body" section begins with:

> "The request body contains data with the following structure:"

Which is followed with the entire `document` object schema and a table that describes each property.

However, at the very top is the following note:

> Creates a blank document using the title given in the request. Other fields in the request, including any provided content, are ignored.

So basically everything on the page is irreverent. Only the `title` property is used ;-(

Answer (score 1):

After replicating your issue I came to the conclusion that you are correct with your findings. To allow creating lists with [`documents.batchUpdate`](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate) I opened a feature request in [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162180193). You could open it and leave a *star* so it gets more popular in the Google engineers eyes.